# Outputting github markdown from bookdown

Tags: r, knitr, github-pages, pandoc, bookdown

I'm trying out this new output format so I can publish to github pages, but am getting the following error:

```
$ Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::markdown_document2')"
Error in base_format(fig_caption = fig_caption, md_extensions = md_extensions,  :   unused argument (fig_caption = fig_caption)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> create_output_format -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

My _output.yml file includes the following lines, per your suggestion:

```
bookdown::markdown_document2:
  base_format: rmarkdown::md_document
  variant: gfm
```

The only related issue I could find was [437](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/437), but I don't see how that helps.